# Historical impact factors of journals

Tags: publications, journals, bibliometrics

Is there any database/resource/website providing the full historical impact factors of a journal?

Scimago gives graphs of citations (kinda IF), but it only backs to 1999. I look for a database having older IFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest exaly over JCR for two reasons:

1. It is completely free and you can reuse both data and graphs.
2. It provides historic impact factors for all journals from their first day (as old as 1665).

For example, this is a graph for Chemical Reviews

[image]
Source: https://exaly.com/journal/14022/chemical-reviews

or Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America

[image]

Source: https://exaly.com/journal/12356/proceedings-of-the-national-academy-of-sciences-of-the-united-states-of-america

Comment: However I would have to ding them for their choice of graph

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- what's the difference with the bar chart of JCR? If drawing a bar chart over a wide range, the bars merge to get the same effect.

Comment: I love how Chemical Reviews is somehow >3x "better" than it was 20 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, check Journal Citation Reports (JCR), published by the company that calculates impact factors (Clarivate). Unfortunately, this is not a free service.

Here's the historical impact factor of *Nature*.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that 3dp accuracy in the axis is a joke.